# PHP/MySQL Issue: Incorrect integer value: '' for column 1

Tags: php, mysql, api

For the following sql statements (inside of php):

```
// Create Table to Hold JSON

$sql = "CREATE TABLE {$value}_GAMES ( ".  // Creating a new table for each team
    "nfl_game_id INT NOT NULL, ".
    "team VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL, ".
    "opponent VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL, ".
    "totfd INT NOT NULL, ".
    "totyds INT NOT NULL, ".
    "pyds INT NOT NULL, ".
    "ryds INT NOT NULL, ".
    "pen INT NOT NULL, ".
    "penyds INT NOT NULL, ".
    "trnovr INT NOT NULL, ".
    "pt INT NOT NULL, ".
    "ptyds INT NOT NULL, ".
    "ptavg INT NOT NULL, ".
    "PRIMARY KEY ( nfl_game_id ));";

$retval = mysql_query($sql, $con); // Execute SQL Code
if(! $retval)
{
die('Could not create table: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo 'Table created successfully\n';


// Process JSON Data

$data = json_decode($result, true); // Decode JSON

foreach($data as $row)
{
$game = $row['nfl_game_id'];
$team = $row['team'];
$opponent = $row['opponent'];
$totfirstdown =$row['totfd'];
$totyds = $row['totyds'];
$pyds = $row['pyds'];
$ryds = $row['ryds'];
$pen = $row['pen'];
$penyds = $row['penyds'];
$trnovr = $row['trnovr'];
$pt = $row['pt'];
$ptyds = $row['ptyds'];
$ptavg = $row['ptavg'];

// Insert data into team-specific table 
$sql = "INSERT INTO {$value}_GAMES(nfl_game_id, team, opponent, totfd, ".
"totyds, pyds, ryds, pen, penyds, trnovr, pt, ptyds, ptavg)".
"VALUES($game, '$team', '$opponent', '$totfirstdown', '$totyds',".
"'$pyds', '$ryds', '$pen', '$penyds', '$trnovr', '$pt', '$ptyds', ".
"'$ptavg')";
$ret_val = mysql_query($sql,$con); // Execute SQL Code
if(! $ret_val)
{
    die('Could not add JSON data to table: ' . mysql_error());
}
}

mysql_close($con); // Close Connection
```

'm getting the following error:

Could not add JSON data to table: Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'nfl_game_id' at row 1
When I echo the API call, this is what the data looks like:

[{"nfl_game_id":2009081350,"team":"ARI","opponent":"PIT","totfd":22,"totyds":329‌​,"pyds":259,"ryds":70,"pen":4,"penyds":27,"trnovr":2,"pt":6,"ptyds":266,"ptavg":3‌​7}, .....

Any idea what's going on?

Comment: Are you sure the value for `nfl_game_id` never exceed mysql int limit of `2147483647` ? I suggest you change the datatype for `nfl_game_id` to BIGINT and give it another try.

Comment: can you print your `$sql` variable and post it here?

Comment: I define $sql twice, they're both up there. And good idea with BIGINT, but it doesn't seem to be the issue

Answer (score 0):

Add single quotes to `$game` variable too.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO {$value}_GAMES(nfl_game_id, team, opponent, totfd, totyds, pyds, ryds, pen, penyds, trnovr, pt, ptyds, ptavg) VALUES('$game', '$team', '$opponent', '$totfirstdown', '$totyds', '$pyds', '$ryds', '$pen', '$penyds', '$trnovr', '$pt', '$ptyds', '$ptavg')";
```

Answer (score 0):

Disabling Strict mode didn't work for me on this error. I'm using MySQL 5.7.15 (according to docs the same valid configs applies since <= 5.7.8)

I played around Until I found out that the only solution was to use

```
UPDATE IGNORE ...
INSERT IGNORE INTO ...
```

Since non strict also fails on this one. and I couldn't afford to replace all occurrences of `ColumnXX = '$possibleEmptyValue'` in order not to need IGNORE.